# How an output of Windows application executed on remote SSH server gets to a local SSH client

Tags: powershell, ssh, putty

I'm using PuTTY to connect to an SSH server running on Windoes 7.

When I issue `powershell` in PuTTY terminal does it mean that the `powershell` command window opens on the remote machine?

If so how does the output from remotely running `powershell` window gets routed to PuTTY client?

Sorry if this is lame question but it's not so obvious to me.

Comment: Which SSH server are you using?

Comment: @ Fang What's the difference what ssh server i'm using? Isn't it all the same for any ssh server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the PowerShell is executed on the remote machine, no window opens on the server.

`powershell.exe` is a console application. Console applications have a standard IO (input and output). If you run a Windows console application locally, Windows GUI creates a console window and binds the application IO to the window. While if you run a console application via an SSH server, the SSH server binds the application IO to the SSH shell session. So anything that the PowerShell prints, gets routed to the SSH shell session output, which ultimately renders in your local SSH client window (PuTTY).

In other words, a local PowerShell window is rendered by Windows GUI (the system that executes the PowerShell), not by the PowerShell process itself (contrary to windows of GUI applications). Another system, like the SSH server, can choose a completely different "rendering" of the IO, like routing the IO to the SSH shell session.

It's the same process like, if you use `ls` command on a *nix server. The `ls` is also a console application. *(Afaik, all *nix applications are actually console applications, what is not true on Windows.)*